# How to update Accumulo visibility label?

Tags: accumulo

We have a scenario in which we need to update Accumulo visibility labels.  My understanding is that visibilities are immutable.    Should we make a copy of the item assigning it the new visibility label and then delete the old one or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Visibility labels in Accumulo are intentionally immutable. You can insert new entries and delete the old ones, or you can extend the [TransformingIterator](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-core/1.7.1/org/apache/accumulo/core/iterators/user/TransformingIterator.html) to convert your old visibility labels to new ones during a major compaction (test with the scan scope first, or test on a cloned table).